# How can I define a function to show that $\{3^n\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is countably infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to answer the following question for an assignment:

> Is the set $A=\{3^{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ finite, countably infinite, or uncountable?

I've defined what I originally thought to be a proper function rule showing a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$, but I've since realized that I'm missing some elements in the codomain.

\begin{equation*}
  f:\mathbb{N}\to A:\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      n\mapsto 3^{n},&\text{if $n=2k-1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$}\\
      n\mapsto 3^{-n},&\text{if $n=2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$}
    \end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}

Here, I noticed that I'm missing all the odd negative numbers and all the even positive numbers.

Is this even doable this way, or do I need to draw a diagram?

I'd much prefer to have a function definition if possible.

Comment: Almost tautologically $|A|=|\Bbb Z|$.

Comment: Do you know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is countably infinite?  If so it's straightforward.  Let $f$ be a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.  Then map each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ onto $3^n$.  Now compose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every $n \in \mathbb Z$, there exists a unique $f(n) \in A$ as defined. That is, and for every number of the form $3^n$, there exists unique $n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $f(n) = 3^n$

The function is a bijection: one-to-one and onto. Hence there is a one-to-one correspondence between $A$ and 
$f(n) = 3^n, \;\;\forall n \in \mathbb Z$

Therefore: $\quad|A| = |\mathbb Z|$

We know $\mathbb Z$ is countably infinite, hence so must be $A$.

---

We can also work to find a bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$, by adjusting your attempt just a bit:

You're definition, with a few adjustments, will work nicely for defining a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$.

Consider

$$f:\mathbb{N}\to A:
\begin{cases} {n\to 3^{\Large\frac{(n-1)}{2}}};& n=2k-1,& k\in\mathbb{N} \\ \\
{ n\to 3^{\Large-\frac{n}{2}}}; & n=2k,& k\in\mathbb{N} \\ \\  
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore $|A| = |\mathbb N|$ which means since $\mathbb N$ is countably infinite, so must be set $A$.$\quad\square$

Comment: But this doesn't show a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$... I'm confused.

Comment: $|\mathbb N| = |\mathbb Z|$.

Comment: Ohh.. ok, I think I see now - But I think for the purposes of this assignment, it'd be more work to do it this way because I'd have to show not only this, but I'd have to demonstrate that $\mathbb{Z}$ is countably infinite first.

Comment: I've defined the bijection from the naturals to the set A: every natural number gets mapped to A, and every element in A has some natural number mapped to it. So it's a nice bijection.  Let me know if this helps! ;-)

Comment: agent154 Let me know if you're okay with this question/my answer. Any questions? Try out any integer n you please, you'll cover all the bases for you bijection from N to A! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: I love it. ;-)

Comment: agent154: feel free to accept an answer, or ask for clarification/elaboration if you are unclear about anything.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there. What if you tried
\begin{equation*}
  f:\mathbb{N}\to A:\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      n\mapsto 3^{(n-1)/2},&\text{if $n=2k-1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$}\\
      n\mapsto 3^{-n/2},&\text{if $n=2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$}
    \end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}

Comment: I like that - didn't think to divide the exponent by two.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea for a mapping in the other direction I think. The negatives to evens, and the positive to odds is a good idea. Consider this $f:A\to \mathbb N$ such that$$f(3^n)=\begin{cases} 2n+1, &n\geq0\\ -2n, &n<0 \end{cases}$$